# Angular Google Maps Correct Strategy

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am new to angular and working on angular based project. Now I have to implement advanced maps functionality list and displaying it like clustering, routing and road routing , paths, directions, polygons, events, drawing on maps, info widows, markers, etc...

I made some search and found that I can use "leaflet" openstreet map but I need to start with Google Maps so I searched and found the following options:

1) I toke a look over ui-map https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map but I am worry since I am not sure if this project is still supported and will cover all the features needed

2) Angular Google Maps https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps very good angularish effort but also worry about the implemented features , may be I can implement external service for not supported features like paths and directions

3) ng-newsletter
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-utils.html

*there are some other solutions like ....

a) using one of ways provided here 
http://wbyoko.co/angularjs/angularjs-google-maps-components.html

b) Implement my directive and use it but worry about how to pass map variable among services

I need advice on which strategy and technology to use beside how to organize my map code among directives and services ?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 seems the best bet out here. Angular UI is widely used library and is well supported.

Check this link http://ngmodules.org/tags/maps for a comparison.